# How to stop divs from moving other divs

Tags: html, css

I need the text Santos Fire Department to say where it is but have the US Server ext. centered. Is there any way to make the divs not collide with each other? I tried position absolute but it just moved the text into the the other buttons.

```css
    li a:hover.nav {
      background-color: #111;
    }

    .navlogo {
      display: block;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      float: left;
      height: 3.3em;
      display: inline-block;
      position:
    }

    li a.navlogo {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      font-size: 150%;
      text-decoration: none;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    ul.nav {
      display: block;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      text-align: center;
      height: 3.3em;

    }

    li a.nav {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="navlogo"><a class="navlogo">Santos Fire Department</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="ts3server://ts.santosrp.com/">TeamSpeak (Temp Server)</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">US Server</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">EU Server</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"><a class="nav" href="https://santosrp.com/">SantosRP</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Man, you have total semantic mess... Please, illustrate the effect you want to reach, for sure there is far more suitable solution for this

Comment: I've not corrected the structure but it is visually what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/mumsj6s8/1/

Answer (score 1):

Class name not same for `ul` and `li`.Please check this code

```css
li a:hover.nav {
    background-color: #111;
}
.navlogo{
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    float:left;
    height: 3.3em;
    display:inline-block;
    position: 
}

li a.navlogo{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

ul.nav{
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    height: 3.3em;
}

li a.nav{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
   .nav li/*for display in one line*/
{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav" >
        <li class="navlogo"><a class="navlogo">Santos Fire Department</a></li>
        <li class="" ><a class="nav" href="ts3server://ts.santosrp.com/">TeamSpeak (Temp Server)</a></li>
        <li class=""><a class="nav" href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">US Server</a></li>
        <li  class=""><a  class="nav" href="steam://connect/158.69.123.91:27015">EU Server</a></li>
        <li class=""><a class="nav" href="https://santosrp.com/">SantosRP</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```